# I need a query to take the name of the territory to which a user belongs

Tags: soql, query, territory-management, territory

**I need a query to take the name of the territory to which a user belongs
I try with this**

UserTerritory userT = [SELECT Id, Terrotory.Name
                                    FROM UserTerritory
                                    WHERE UserId = :currentUser LIMIT 1];

**but throws this error**

SELECT Id, Territory.Name
           ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:12
Didn't understand relationship 'Territory' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Answer (score 0):

Because you can not use relationships with the UserTerritory object. You can query UserTerritory for the TerritoryID, and then query Territory using that ID to get the Name.